# Is it possible to copy a worksheet so that worksheet references are transfered relatively to the new workskeet?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

Sheet1 has A1 = 1, B1 = 2.

Sheet2 has A1 = Sheet1!A1, B1 = Sheet1!B1

I'd like to be able to make a copy of Sheet2 so that A1 = Sheet2!A1, B1 = Sheet2!B1.  This would basically work the same way as if I copied cell B1 which contained =A1 and pasted it into cell B2 so that the formula would be =A2.  Basically, I'd like to fill across worksheets just like you can fill across cells.

At the very least, it would be nice to be able to copy the range of cells that reference the previous sheet and paste them into the next sheet so that their relative references are preserved.

Does at least Excel 2007 have something like this?

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately Excel does not have a reference relative to the current sheet, like "previous sheet" or "next sheet" in the list of sheets. This feature has been suggested to Microsoft by Excel MVPs a number of times, but so far has not been implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the sheet, then on that sheet do a find and replace to add the sheet name. If you do it enough, it may be worth creating a procedure in VBA to do it automatically.